JUnit test to compare specifications
I have a method that creates a Specification from a user role. I am trying to create a junit test to see if the output is well created.
In this example I am providing, the user with an IP role, and the specification resulted should only contain a check of its process name.
@InjectMocks
private CbdAccessServiceBusiness cbdAccessServiceBusiness;

@Mock
private MyUser myUser;

@Test
void when_user_is_ip_then_returns_specification_with_only_its_industrial_process() {
        // Given
        IndustrialProcessEntity ip = randomlyGenerateOne(IndustrialProcessEntity.class);
        when(myUser.getRole()).thenReturn(IP);
        when(myUser.getIndustrialProcess()).thenReturn(ip);

        // When
        Specification<CbdEntity> spec = cbdAccessServiceBusiness.deductSpecificationsFromUserRights();

        // Then
        Specification<CbdEntity> expectedSpec = CbdSpecifications.processIn(List.of(ip.getName()));
        assertEquals(expectedSpec, spec);
}

Though the assertEquals can't work as two instances of specification are created. WHat I would like to be able is to compare the content of both specification.
